# How to heavily weight exact query text in solr rather than results containing it as a substring?

Tags: apache, elasticsearch, solr, lucene, query-analyzer

I'm working with name searching and, for some reason, when I query *"sam"* documents containing the query as a sub-string like *"samara"*, *"samir"*, or *"samuel"* are returned with seemingly equal weight.

Is this just a built-in feature of Solr to parse words containing your search term as a sub-string? Is there a way to apply greater weight to the exact query itself before then moving on to alternatives?

I already have two separate `fieldTypes` to weight the original text more heavily than it's synonyms, but I couldn't figure out a way around this substring problem as it appears to be inherent to Solr.

Here is my fieldType definition:

```
<fieldType class="solr.TextField" name="fullTextName" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">

        <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>

    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible in Solr :

1) you define 2 field types : fullTextName and fullTextNameExact
   the difference between them will be the indexing time analysis, specifically you want the exact field type to not have the edge Ngram token filter.

2) You create 2 fields, one per each type

3) you define a request handler that uses the dismax query parser or edismax query parser.[1]

4) one request parameter to use is the "qf", this param allows you to express different fields to be involved in search, weighting them with different boosts.
In your case you could use :

```
<str name="qf">fullTextNameExact^3 fullTextName</str>
```

This will boost stronger exact match results but still allow for autocompletion.

[1] https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Extended+DisMax+Query+Parser

Comment: I'm confused though-- I did what you suggested with these two separate fields, but even when I only specify to "query field" in the `exactName` field (the one with no `EdgeNgramFilter`) I still hit documents that have substring matches. Like q=sam, and a result may be samir. Could I be missing something else? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post here the fieldType definition for the fieldType you used for exactName ?
As I mentioned this field type should not have edge Ngram token filtering.

Comment: I included it in the post

Comment: As I mentioned it should not have edge ngram token filtering.
Only the field type for the partial search should.

Comment: Oh sorry, it doesn't have that anymore. EdgeGram is commented out in the one I'm using.